# Adding New block in customer layout

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

```
<block type="customer/account_dashboard_mydesigns" name="customer_account_dashboard_mydesigns" as="mydesigns"   template="customer/mydesigns.phtml"/>
```

Above code does not load mydesign.phtml file. But It loads when I change `as="mydesigns"` to `as="info"`. As I change so, magento fails to load info.phtml.

```
<block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
```

Comment: You have to provide the complete layout block (with reference) in your questions to get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need call your block at `customer/account/dashboard.phtml` using child block

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mydesigns') ?>` Other wise it not render.

**layout code look like:**

```
<reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
<block type="customer/account_dashboard_mydesigns" name="customer_account_dashboard_mydesigns" as="mydesigns"   template="customer/mydesigns.phtml"/>

 </reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a block to the layout.xml isn't enough in the most cases. It depends on the parent block if your custom block is displayed.

If the parent block

- has the type "core/text_list" it will display all child blocks automatically (you can reorder them with the before and after attributes)
- inherits of "core/template" it won't be displayed automatically. In this case you have to add the following code into the template file (.phtml) of the parent block

Display your block:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mydesigns'); ?>
```

The change to "info" works, because another block has the same name or alias. This is not allowed!